# How do I get an Epson Stylus S21 to print from Windows 7 via Airport USB Printer Sharing?

Tags: windows-7, printer, airport-extreme

I’ve got an Epson Stylus S21 printer hooked up to my Airport Extreme via USB. I’m trying to print to it from Windows 7, but I’m not sure how to set it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install [Bonjour Print Services](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl999) on the Windows 7 machine.
2. Download the bare driver installer from the Epson website (http://www.epson.co.uk/Store/Printers-and-All-in-Ones/Epson-Stylus-S21/Drivers-Support)
3. Run the driver installer.
4. Within the driver installer, select the “manual” option instead of “USB”.
5. When the list of available printers comes up, there should be a Bonjour printer listed. Select that one.